# Typescript: how do I most explicitly define a variable that can hold a function name or that function's return type?

Tags: typescript

I'm refactoring/rebuilding an existing codebase, and came across the equivalent of this code:

```
class FeedbackBase {
    Variables = [{Value: 'doSomething'}];

    goToFeedback() {

        this.Variables?.forEach(variable => {
            if (variable.Value) {
                variable.Value = (this[variable.Value])();
            }
        });
    }

    doSomething(): string { return '123';}
}
```

The basic idea is that `Variables[].Value` might contain a function call defined on `FeedbackBase`. If it does, then run the function, and replace `Variables[].Value` with the return value.

Before `this.Variables?.forEach`, they were originally doing a deep copy of `this.Variables`, wiping out all of the typing and basically running the code on an 'any' object. When we keep the typing, Typescript complains about `this[variable.Value]`:

`Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'FeedbackBase'. No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'FeedbackBase'.`

Fair enough: all Typescript knows is that the contents of `variable.Value` are a `string`: it doesn't know whether it is a callable function on `FeedbackBase`.

My potential solution:

```
type BaseFunction = {
    doSomething(): string;
};

class FeedbackBase implements BaseFunction {
    Variables = [{Value: 'doSomething'}];

    goToFeedback() {
        this.Variables?.forEach(variable => {
            if (variable.Value) {
                variable.Value = this[variable.Value as keyof BaseFunction]();
            }
        })
    }

    doSomething(): string { return '123';}
}
```

Basically:

1. Within `BaseFunction`, explicitly define all of the functions that could be defined in `variable.Value`
2. `FeedbackBase implements BaseFunction`
3. Call the function as `this[variable.Value as keyof BaseFunction]` to tell Typescript that this should be treated as a function call, not as a string.

A nice feature of this approach is that when you say `this[variable.Value as keyof BaseFunction]`, Typescript checks to make sure that `this` indeed has all of the functions defined in `BaseFunction`. (For example, if you change `FeedbackBase.doSomething` to `FeedbackBase.doSomethings`, an error appears at `this[variable.Value as keyof BaseFunction]`).

I think that, in this case, I'm forced to use `as`, because `variable.Value` could be `keyof BaseFunction`, or whatever is returned by the function call. Even if I get more specific about the return type, I can't think of a way to define `variable.Value` as definitely a function call before the transformation, and definitely a return type afterward, outside of just using `as`.

Is there a way to be more explicit?

Comment: I am a bit lost with this pattern. How does your `FeedBackBase` class receive its `Variables` array?, what kind of mistakes should Typescript gard you against? Should `Variables` be allowed to contain `Properties` which don't exist in the instance? I agree with Jack but that's just me on auto-pilot, I don't understand what I am reading

Comment: I simplified the code to hopefully illustrate the scenario more effectively. I'm happy to answer your questions, but if you have a chance, please have a look at the simplified code just to see whether you still need answers.

Comment: You should rethink your API. This is not really a good design, and this attempt at translating it to TS kinda proves it. If statically typing something is hard, it may be a code smell. Consider making a function that returns the transformed Variables array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TS would not allow you to do that if it knew what you wanted to do, and I think it would be right in complaining. This is what this answer will attempt to demonstrate.

You don't need an interface to wire the types. You can statically work out the names of `FeedbackBase` non-void method names like so:

```js
type NonVoidMethodNames<Class> = keyof {
    [K in keyof Class
        as ((...args: any[]) => void) extends Class[K] ? never
        : Class[K] extends (...args: any[]) => unknown ? K
        : never
    ]: K
}

type DoSomething = NonVoidMethodNames<FeedbackBase> // "doSomething"
```

If you assigned it to `Variables` like the following, you would not need your `as` when you call `this[variable.Value]()`.

```js
Variables: { Value: NonVoidMethodNames<FeedbackBase> }[] = [{ Value: 'doSomething' }];
```

TS would try to index `this` with `"doSomething"`, realise it's a method, no problem, and work out the return type as `string` as expected

But of course we can't simply do that because now we're assigning `string` to `variable.Value` which we had defined to be `"doSomething"`.

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiCm8AmAjMwDWAhS9oG8BYAKGjOgDUwAnASzBRHggC4DKwQBXeNgOQD2AOwoDaSALLwALgAsBSPmAC2zADwJkaTDgjwAfNAC+AbQC60ALzQT+Kt17QA5EgEBlAarm0hAcydGZgDcJCTk0L4CACoCmqjoGAAUAJQEYeHk3hAAdFR0DEw5AGYC1ACi6LKJAG409Ix4loZEpBlttEXQNXUF8LmcPKktbSPkwMIQ0tDUzFwgU9ZZJrX5Df0OZikhraNtK-VM6zxW0Ev7vUfwm8nbu+RG6W1GyY-GoTvQrh5esj6+KWxJnQ-OwZtIuNQhM4AIwAJgAzE4gg9iCiSNIAJ4ABzwghEYkkMnkihU6gAwuAoIZrBh4BiBJ1huQTABpaA+aC0+mdCmQCCvcKQLqJbKimi+VjQMBCDHmVJNaDVAmpeAAD2k8CESBgvKgrIsAH5oEJ4NV4NQBeQ2LqIProGqNVqYCKxdQJWxpbKzPLDFwhBghAIAO5Qo0sy1kNgms0Wj5mNjh1HvTE4z7uTxEv4nPGicRSOQKJSqCAaRDxHS4fRAA)

In TS, you can't write the following and this is the situation you are in, only with indirections in-between.

```js
let foo: string = 'a';
foo = 1;
```

You would also be inconvenienced if you wanted to widen `Value` to `MethodName | ReturnType` when the return type is `string` as it is the case here because `string` would swallow its subtypes.

Even ignoring the problem of when `Variables` is populated, the user has no way to know what values this field contains. This is a deal breaker in my opinion. I am not very savvy in OO but I would say this design is flawed and cannot be typed.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the *best* TypeScript per say because it seems a bit convoluted, but I think your solution is fine in terms of typings. I would beware of one thing though.

I don't think the `forEach` does what you want it to. If a `Value` is not a function, you'll get a runtime error because you're not actually checking if `Value` is a function. Instead, you're checking if it exists.

```js
this.Variables?.forEach((variable) => {
      if (
        variable.Value &&
        variable.Value in this &&
        typeof this[variable.Value as keyof BaseFunction] === "function"
      ) {
        variable.Value = this[variable.Value as keyof BaseFunction]()
      }
})
```

Comment: Ah, great point. They do something similar in other files, but not in this one, thanks for catching that. `variable.Value in this` is also a very helpful check.